# Why am I getting an error when I disengage world wrap in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I downloaded a working model and I'm adjusting it to fit criteria I have.  I want to disable the world wrap so the turtles are constrained in their movement to the initial screen but when I do I get an error telling me: OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle or patch but got NOBODY instead.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  For future reference, your question is a bit incomplete as it's hard for others to help you without seeing the code you are using.  Try to include enough code for others to answer your question.  I cannot directly help resolve your issue, but I can provide some general information.

In NetLogo the behavior of many of the language primitives changes when world wrapping is enabled and when it is not.  As an example using `patch-ahead`, in a world with wrapping in both directions, this code will always succeed:

```
; turtles will color themselves the color of the patch 1 unit away
ask turtles [
  set color ([pcolor] of patch-ahead 1)
]
```

But if wrapping is disabled in one or both directions, [the `patch-ahead` of a turtle can return `nobody`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-ahead) when there is no patch in front of the turtle because the turtle is at the edge of the world.  In that case you are asking NetLogo to evaluate `[pcolor] of nobody`, but that is not possible, and you get an error like the one you described.

To resolve this issue you'll have to look through the code and see where these errors are made and handle them appropriately.  For my example:

```
ask turtles [
  if patch-ahead 1 != nobody [
    set color ([pcolor] of patch-ahead 1)
  ]
]
```

You can read more about [the world topology of NetLogo models in the docs](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology).